# How to hide/clear badge when click on one position of bottom navigation menu in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, badge, bottomnavigationview

I am getting stuck at hiding the badge from `NavigationView`. When I get any notification added badge with position of `BottomNavigationNiew` but could not refresh that batch when click the position.

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.1.7'
compile 'q.rorbin:badgeview:1.1.0'
```

MainActivity:

```
private Badge addBadgeAt(int position, int number) {
        return new QBadgeView(this)
                .setBadgeNumber(number)
                .setGravityOffset(42, 2, true)
                .bindTarget(bottomNavigationView.getBottomNavigationItemView(position)); 
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_conection:

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, ConnectionFragment.newInstance("connection"));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;
        case R.id.menu_me:
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, MyProfile.newInstance(ARG_TYPE));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;

        case R.id.menu_notification:

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, NotificationsFragment.newInstance());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I just want to removed the badge at the second position when click `menu_notification`

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void removeBadge(int position, BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx, QBadgeView badgeView) {
badgeView.bindTarget(bottomNavigationViewEx.getBottomNavigationItemView(position))
                .hide(true);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

When you call addBadgeAt function, you need to assign the returned `Badge` object to a variable:

```
mBadge = addBadgeAt(2, 1);
```

Then, when you want to remove the badge, simply call `hide` method:

```
mBadge.hide(true);
```

**CAUTION: Seems that call two times the hide method cause the badge to be visible again.**

You can check out the docs here: https://github.com/qstumn/BadgeView